# Centrar Codigo de footer PHP Divi Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Hola tengo el siguiente código, estoy trabajando con Wordpress y el constructor llamado DIVI Builder además del theme o template llamado DIVI, no he logrado centrar los iconos ni siquiera con un DIV.

```
<div align="center">
   <img src="http://logo.png" alt="Facebook"><br>
</div>

<ul class="et-social-icons">
   <?php if ( 'on' === et_get_option( 'divi_show_facebook_icon', 'on' ) ) : ?>
   <li class="et-social-icon et-social-facebook">
      <img src="http://Facebook.png" alt="Facebook">
      <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Facebook', 'Divi' ); ?></span>
      </a>
   </li>
   <?php endif; ?>
   <?php if ( 'on' === et_get_option( 'divi_show_instagram_icon', 'on' ) ) : ?>
   <li class="et-social-icon et-social-twitter">
      <img src="http://Instagram.png" alt="Instagram">  
      <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Twitter', 'Divi' ); ?></span>
      </a>
   </li>
   <?php endif; ?>
   <?php if ( 'on' === et_get_option( 'divi_show_twitter_icon', 'on' ) ) : ?>
   <li class="et-social-icon et-social-twitter">
      <img src="http://Twitter.png" alt="Twitter">
      <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Twitter', 'Divi' ); ?></span>
      </a>
   </li>
   <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

El logo de la empresa si esta centrado, solo me falta centrar los iconos de redes sociales, porque se me centrar al pasar a responsive

Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 1):

Sin ver mejor tu código es imposible pero ¿porque no pones un div englobando a los ul con la clase centrar?.

```
<div align="center">
   <img src="http://logo.png" alt="Facebook"><br>
</div>

<div class="div_centrado">
<ul class="et-social-icons">
   <?php if ( 'on' === et_get_option( 'divi_show_facebook_icon', 'on' ) ) : ?>
   <li class="et-social-icon et-social-facebook">
      <img src="http://Facebook.png" alt="Facebook">
      <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Facebook', 'Divi' ); ?></span>
      </a>
   </li>
   <?php endif; ?>
   <?php if ( 'on' === et_get_option( 'divi_show_instagram_icon', 'on' ) ) : ?>
   <li class="et-social-icon et-social-twitter">
      <img src="http://Instagram.png" alt="Instagram">  
      <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Twitter', 'Divi' ); ?></span>
      </a>
   </li>
   <?php endif; ?>
   <?php if ( 'on' === et_get_option( 'divi_show_twitter_icon', 'on' ) ) : ?>
   <li class="et-social-icon et-social-twitter">
      <img src="http://Twitter.png" alt="Twitter">
      <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Twitter', 'Divi' ); ?></span>
      </a>
   </li>
   <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Y ahora en CSS ponle o lo que necesites a tu clase div_centrado para que salga en la posición que necesites.

```
.div_centrado{
/*Es un ejemplo*/
text-align: center;
padding:25px
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Agrega afuera de ul un DIV como el siguiente:

```
<div align="center">
    <ul class="et-social-icons">
        ...
    </u>
</div>
```